# how to write dynamic query in azure stream analytics?

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

For an instance, simulated device storing humidity to blob storage. How can I write a query (humidity > X) so that X is picked from another file in blob storage. This X can vary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reference data for storing the thresholds (X in above example). Reference data can either be static, or dynamic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-use-reference-data